# password is incorrect - when tried to login into ubuntu 13.04

Tags: password

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 with dual boot to Win 7 without any issue. The login screen came up on Ubuntu with two accounts (Guest & myname). I was able to login as guest but not through my name it said "Invalid password please try again". I have tried all possible passwords that i know off. Could anyone please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Try to login via tty1. ie: hit **alt+ctrl+f1** and give your username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you remember the password you put on installation?
Do you put any pass? Try without any pass.

If this don't result, try:

[How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)